# PopUp View not crossing the bounds of the screen - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have UIView which is a pop up menu, it appears when i long press the screen. But when i the very edge of the screen, it crosses the border of the screen.

How to prevent it?

Thank you

Comment: You can do this by writing some code.

Comment: Just change the width of the pop-up UIView. Perhaps you can give us some code ?